# Please help me setting up htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

consider i have a site example.com. i want to setup htaccess to remove every thing that appears after trailing slash in the url part. for example if some one enters example.com/test/blog, it should be converted to example.com/test

plus I want one url structure to be given exception of this rule. any thing that appears as example.com/**member**/first should NOT be touched. so member profile urls should not be touched. rest every url should be passed through the check defined above and truncated if required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*/member/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) $1/
```